# 3 Dimensional matrix in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

How can i represent a 1x1x3 matrix in python.In matlab i have

```
fill_value(1,1,:) = [0; 0; 0];
```

I have converted this to python as

```
fill_value[0:1] = matrix(((0),(0),(0))).T
```

But it is not giving the expected result.

Comment: What library is matrix in?

Comment: Does `my_matrix = [[ [0,0,0] ]]` suite your needs? I'm not sure if you are using a matrix class from another library or not. Have you looked into numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write `1x1x3 matrix` using numpy.

```
import numpy
fill_value = numpy.array([[[0, 0, 0]]])
```

when we check

```
resol_val = fill_value.shape
```

output will be `(1, 1, 3)`

Answer (score 3):

Using standard Python objects? Like this:

```
>>> fill_value = [[[1, 2, 3]]]
>>> fill_value[0][0][0]
1
>>> fill_value[0][0][1]
2
>>> fill_value[0][0][2]
3
```

You probably want to look into numpy though, which has much better support for [matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html).